# How can we theme menu blocks in drupal 6

Tags: theming, blocks

I decide to theme menu blocks in my drupal 6.x.

I have copied **block.tpl.php** into my theme folder and I have renamed it to **block-menu.tpl.php**

**but it seems it doesn't work !!**

How can I modify the theme for menu blocks?

Answer (score 1):

You can user the [theme developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) to check whether your template is called at all. It will show you what nameing conventions to use.

And just in case: You have to flush your caches to make sure new templates and theming methods are taken into account.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this module but I searched about this issue and I found that block-menu.tpl.php doesn't work in drupal 6

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the problem is you re-named `block.tpl.php` `block-menu.tpl.php` instead of **copying it as it works** for me here.  If it doesn't for you, or you want to theme a specific menu block, you can do something like this:

1. Copy the default `block.tpl.php` to your theme's directory if it's not already there.
2. Examine your html source and look for the ID of any block, eg 
   `<div id="block-menu-my-menu" ....>` and then,
   id=
3. Create a new `block-menu-my-menu.tpl.php` in your theme's directory, eg, block-BLOCK_ID.tpl.php.

You need to have **BOTH** otherwise Drupal 6 won't look for the specific block template override.

In either case, you have to clear the cache after creating both templates.

Now you should be able to theme this specific menu block.
For good measure, if you want to keep things clean, you can also **create a directory** structure for all of the templates, eg, create a **tpl directory** and then in there have subdirectories like `block, node, page, etc,` and put all your various templates in there.

ADDITION:

To be more precise, read: [Drupal 6 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089642)

> What's a template suggestion? It's an alternate template
>   `(.tpl.php)` file that you have created to override the base or
>   original template file. *Suggestions only work when they are placed in
>   the same directory as the base templates.*  In other words, if you
>   want `comment-blog.tpl.php` to display in your browser,
>   **comment.tpl.php** also needs to exist inside your theme's folder and the two files must be in the same directory. 
>   `comment.tpl.phpcomment.tpl.php`

MORE ADDITIONS:

I am not sure what kind of development environment you have, but hopefully it is similar to [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html), which I use for quick stuff on my MacBook:

> 1. cd /applications/mamp/htdocs/modules/system
> 2. cp block.tpl.php /applications/mamp/htdocs/sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME
> 3. cd /applications/mamp/htdocs/sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME
> 4. cp block.tpl.php block-menu.tpl.php

Now, if YOURTHEME already has a `block.tpl.php`, you can omit step 2, but just make sure that when all is said and done somewhere in or under the YOURTHERE directory,  there is a directory that contains both `block.tpl.php` and `block-menu.tpl.php`. It could be in the base level directory, it could be in a subdirectory, regardless, just make sure both files are there.  Also, make sure that YOURTHEME doesn't have a `block.tpl.php` elsewhere.  If it does, make sure that `block-menu.tpl.php` is in that directory, eg, that you don't have two sets of `block.tpl.php` and `block-menu.tpl.php` files in different directories in YOURTHEME's directory structure for that would be confusing the theme registry build process and it would pick up only one of them.

Clear all caches to make sure the theme registry is rebuilt to see these new templates.  If you have the [Admin Menu](https://drupal.org/project/Admin_Menu) module installed you can do this easily from the leftmost dropdown menu.

Now you can edit `block-menu.tpl.php` to theme all blocks created by the menu module.

Comment: Indeed, I want to theme ALL menu blocks. not specific menu block by ID.

Comment: so just make sure you COPY `block.tpl.php` to `block-menu.tpl.php` and flush caches to make sure it's noticed and you should be all set to go.

Comment: I had done this before. please read my first topic. block-menu.tpl.php doesn't work in drupal 6

Comment: well, I don't know what to tell you then, because I am running drupal 6 and it works just fine here.

Comment: it is very confusing.. please tell me , have you written some codes in template.php file ??!

Comment: I have lots of stuff in template.php but nothing related to this question.   where have you read that this doesn't work?

Comment: Really I did  it by using PHP string functions inside page.tpl.php file. I invoked the string of tree menu into a variable and then removed the extra tags buy str_replace method.

Comment: I've added some more additions to the main answer.